# Redirect on returning to site

Tags: 7, redirection

In my site when a user logs in he is redirected to the profile page(profile2 module). But when returns to the site(and is already logged in), he is taken to the user account page. How do I override this redirect and see to that he is take to profile page?

UPDATE:
The user must be redirected from the site frontpage which contains the user login form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Rules module, force user to redirect to whatever page after login. It's very easy to get it done via the Rules UI, try it out. http://drupal.org/project/rules

Comment: As I mentioned in my question... the user redirect __after login__ is perfectly fine. It is part where a _logged in user returns to the site_. (Eg: on typing example.com on the address bar he should be taken to the profile page).